# How should I make Unity wait for an animation to end completely?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where characters, as expected, have animations to portray their actions. While some of them (like running) can be interrupted to start new animations, others (like attacking or getting damaged) need to be played in full length before these characters can do anything else (like moving again). To achieve such, I need to retrieve each animation's length (unless there's something I'm forgetting).

The problem is: animation clips cannot be easily accessed at runtime. It seems like I can only Get them when they're loaded in the animator, which is not ideal for my purpose.

To retrieve the length of animations, I came up with a couple of solutions, but I have some issues with all of them. My question is:
Which of these methods is the one considered the best practice? Or: is there a method considered to be the best practice that is not listed here? Or finally: is the best practice to make sure the animations get completed using a technique relying on something I'm not thinking about?

Here are my solutions:
**- Referencing each animation clip in the inspector:**
The most straightforward solution, but most likely the messiest in the long run. By having many characters with many animations each (enemies, bosses, etc) having to drag all the animations in the inspector feels like it's gonna take quite some time, and every time a reference is lost, I'd have to repeat the whole process again. It really feels like this process could be automatized.

**- Hardcoding everything:**
I already know the length of each animation. I could make some constants and write down the lengths by hand, which would surely work, until an animation gets changed and someone forgets to update the constants. This could go unnoticed for months and become a major issue later.

**- Retrieving the length of the animation at runtime, just when it starts to play**
I feel like this strategy can make an impact on performance that I could avoid, since the system would have to Get the animation every time from the Animator. If I had the values already stored somewhere else, the process would be much smoother. This may create bugs as well, since the system may require a moment to update the animator before getting values from the clip.

**- Using AssetBundle or Resources folder**
This way, I can access all my clips any time I want. It feels like a big sacrifice for a small return though. I only need to get the length of my animations at the beginning and store them somewhere. In this scenario, I'm keeping many files loaded, impacting on performance, for something I only need at the beginning of the runtime.

**- Fiddling with the Animator to get what I want all at once**
I can theoretically make the Animators of every character cycle through every animation just to save the values. It should work, but as far as I tried, it's very buggy. Again, most likely because the Animator needs a moment to load each animation before retrieving the data of each clip properly.

**- Using AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<>()**
Which should work, but may create all the problems related to anything that can be Editor-only. This last solution feels like the best, to me. I'm sure every developer making a game faced this problem at some point, and it feels a bit weird that this should be the solution though.

Thank you already for all the support!

Comment: A lot of this is purely based on assumptions .. `can make an impact on performance`, `This may create bugs as well,` .. try. If it doesn't work fast enough you can still iterate and improve later on but for now I wouldn't be too concerned about performance as this is not really a processing heavy operation to get the current state and clip information..

Comment: Especially getting all clips can easily be achieved using [`AnimationUtility.GetAnimationClips`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationUtility.GetAnimationClips.html) .. all currently playing clips using [`Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo.html)

Comment: Why not use an AnimationController? Then you can specify per transition if it should happen immediately, or only at the end of the currently playing animation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you control your animations with transitions, you can check “Has Exit Time” at the settings in the inspector of the transitions from the animation you want to be played in full length.

Answer (score 0):

To know the animation is finish you have some options:

1. Use `AnimationEvent`, add one to your last key frame of the animation.
   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent
2. Use `AnimatorStateInfo`

   ```
    if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime > 1f)
    {
        Debug.Log("Animation done.");
    }
   ```